# how to geotag a picture?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, geotagging

I need to tag my images with location details. If I wish to enable/disable the geotagging, I should do it on a button click. (like, we can enable/disable the location details while we chat using Whatsapp, Facebook, Viber etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to Worklight really.

Worklight embeds Cordova inside the generated project.
You can take the picture using Cordova APIs as well as add the location the image was snapped at.

Here is one reference: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Camera_Pic_%26_GeoTagging_App_using_PhoneGap

As for the UI, to disable/enable, this is purely *applicative*. Once you get the image taking and tagging to work, you can base this on "button clicks".

Answer (score 0):

In worklight, we can use the below link for adding location details. I tried and worked for me.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

for Android environment, add Permission, copy the following lines.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

It worked in IOS also. (xcode 5.1.1)